# How to run Cypress tests from a container with opening browser (non-headlessly)?

Tags: docker, cypress

I'm trying to run Cypress tests non-headlessly (I know how to run them headlessly) to have it
open Firefox and run all the tests. In the docs it's stated that all I need to do
is run `cypress run --browser firefox` which is for when you install cypress using npm package manager. I'm using containerized Cypress.

structure of the container:

```
cypress
   - integration
   - cypress.json
   - plugins
   - node_modules
```

Apparently I can run `docker run -it -v $PWD:/services/cypress -w / --entrypoint=cypress tdd_cypress --browser firefox run` which throws an error in my case.

**EDIT:**

I ran the command again to see what's actually happening and it seems it is working but it's running the tests within the container. I came into this conclusion after seeing this when I pressed Ctrl+C:

```
^CThe Test Runner unexpectedly exited via a exit event with signal SIGINT

Please search Cypress documentation for possible solutions:

https://on.cypress.io

Check if there is a GitHub issue describing this crash:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues

Consider opening a new issue.

----------

Platform: linux (Debian - 10.3)
Cypress Version: 4.8.0
```

^ this made me think that the tests are indeed running I just can't see them running because they're running **within** the container (which is fine if I run tests headlessly in CI).

How do I run tests with browser opening having Cypress running in a container ?

Comment: Show the error message

Comment: @NeelKamath I added an edit to my post.

Comment: Does it run in the container fine in headless mode (i.e., are you sure the tests aren't broken when run in the container)?

Comment: Answering from another account. Yes, I can confirm I can run  tests headlessly because I can run `docker logs container --follow` and it spits out the results of the tests. I'd like to know how to run them live though.